# get how many seconds this thread ran

Tags: java, multithreading, nanotime

hey i have this function in my code:

```
public synchronized void finished()
{
    howManyDone++;
    log.append("Finished creating board "+this.howManyDone+"\n");
    if(howManyDone == boards.length)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(log, "All Boards Were Created.","Attention",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

i want to add to the log.append command how much evrey thread ran in sec.
i tried to do this one:

```
public synchronized void finished()
{
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    howManyDone++;
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long estTime = end - start;
    double seconds = (double)estTime/1000000000;
}
```

and than print the seconds in each time like this:

```
log.append("Finished creating board " +this.howManyDone+ " in "+seconds+"\n");
```

but the numbers i get in the log as the seconds appears like that: 6.00E-7 and so on...
what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: You are only timing the number of seconds the finished function runs, not the threads.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible to get the total run time unless you were able to note the system time when the thread *started* work. Simply calling it at the start of the finished function won't be enough.

For one solution, you could create a `Thread` subclass that keeps track of how long it runs, as such:

```
public class TimedThread extends Thread {

    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;

    public TimedThread(Runnable r) {
        super(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        super.run();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public long getRunDuration() {
        return endTime - startTime;
    }
}
```

Then use `TimedThread`s instead of `Threads` where you need a timing calculation (assuming you hae control over that section of code).